# javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity() stuck in infinite loop

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jersey

I'm using `Foo f = response.readEntity(Foo.class)` to get an entity from a javax.ws.rs.core.Response object.

The problem is that the statement is seemingly stuck in a loop (using 100% of the CPU according to htop) until the JVM finally terminates from lack of memory.

I've tried looking into it with the debugger, but the function is time-sensitive and the service throws a `TimeoutException` when I try to execute a step-by-step trace.

Comment: Can you show the `Foo` class and an example JSON (or whatever type of data) so we can test it out.

Comment: @peeskillet: Here's the [class](http://pastebin.com/Sy9HEiLt) and here's the [JSON](http://pastebin.com/0myUyS2k).

Comment: Can't test without `Track` and whatever the `Track.trackSegments` property is. Check to make sure you don't have an circular dependencies in those classes. That is my first guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not directly related to the `readEntity()` function: the query parameters weren't being sent correctly to the API, so the search arguments ended up being `null` in the SQL query. This, coupled with the default behavior of the database being to return the *complete dataset* if no arguments were passed, resulted in the `readEntity()` method being passed too many entries to process (neither infinite nor a loop).

If anyone else ever has a `readEntity()` freeze up, consider the possibility that you are inadvertently passing an inordinate amount of data in the Response object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 1K of data can be deemed inordinate :) I opened this https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/4081 with a reproducer (mentioned in the issue) about a week ago. In my case the client isn't using 100% of the CPU; it is blocked on readEntity()